# How to prove that $0$ sum could be reached

Tags: geometry, symmetry

I have $n$ random points $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n$ on the unit circle. Points are uniformly distributed.

I want to think about the points as associated angles $\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots, \theta_n$ that are uniformly picked in $(-\pi, \pi]$.

Suppose, we rotate the circle, thus $\theta_i$ is a function of the angle $\theta$ of the new axis in the original frame.

For example, if $\theta_1 = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and we rotate the circle $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ in the positive direction, then $\theta_1\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right) = \dfrac{2}{3}\pi$.

Angles are adjusted to always stay in $(-\pi, \pi]$ range. See the animation below

[image: visualize sums with three angles]

Denote $S_{\theta} \triangleq \theta_1(\theta) + \theta_2(\theta) + \ldots + \theta_n(\theta)$.

> Does there exist a rotation $\theta$ such that $S_{\theta} = 0$ ?

My gut feeling, is that *yes*. But I do not see a direction to prove the claim.

What  I have done, is that rotating a circle clock-wise creates $S_{\theta}$ monotonically decreasing, except, when a point "crosses a negative X axis", at that point $2\pi$ are added.

But I don't see why $S_{\theta}$ changes the sign. It could stay negative or positive always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, such a value exists.

First, let's understand how any of the $\theta_i(\theta)$ functions looks like. Let's choose the direction of rotation such that $\theta_i(\theta)$ increases, unless it encounters the discontinuity jumping between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. In that case, $\theta_i(\theta)$ is just a linear function, increasing with slope $1$. If it reaches the value $\pi$, it will jump to $-\pi$ and continue from there linearly with slope 1 until again the value reaches $\pi$, which happens at an increment of $\theta$ of exactly $2\pi$.

So it's easy to see understand that $\theta_i(\theta)$ is $2\pi$-periodic (rotating the circle by $\theta+2\pi$ leaves the new axis in exactly the same position as rotating it by $\theta$). For a starting value of e.g. $\theta_i(0)=\frac{\pi}3$, the function looks like this:

[image: Function plot]

The key insight now is that, no matter the starting value of $\theta_i(0)$, the Rieman integral of $\theta_i(\theta)$ over $[0,2\pi]$ is always zero. One can do this by hand calculation, but an easier way to see this is to realize that because the function is  $2\pi$-periodic, the integral doesn't change when one moves the integration interval around, as long as the length stays at $2\pi$.

In this case, we can choose the interval to be $[-\theta_i(0),2\pi-\theta_i(0)]$, which means the function will always look like this in this interval, starting from $0$ up to $\pi$, the jumping down to $-\pi$ and climb back up to $0$.

[image: function plot to show integral is 0]

The integral over the positive part of the function cancels the integral over the negative part exactly.

We are almost done now!

Since $S(\theta)$ (I'll use that instead of $S_\theta$ to stress the function character) equals $\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i(\theta)$, we get

$$ \int_0^{2\pi}S(\theta) = \int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n\int_0^{2\pi}\theta_i(\theta) = 0.$$

In order for $S(\theta)$'s integral to be $0$, there must be positive and negative function values (if all were $0$, we would be done already). So there exist $x_1, x_2$ with $S(x_1) < 0, S(x_2) > 0$. Since $S(\theta)$ is of course also $2\pi$-periodic, we can assume $x_1 < x_2$.

$S(\theta)$ is the sum of piecewise increasing functions, so $S(\theta)$ is as well. $S(x_1)$ is negative, from here $S(\theta)$ increases (linearly, so continuosly) until it reaches a point of discontinuity, where it jumps **down** by $2\pi$. So if it reached function value $0$ during the linear increase, we found what we were looking for. If not, it was still negative when the jump happened, so it is still negative after the jump **down**, when the function will again start to rise.

But we know that the function will reach a positve value at point $x_2$, so at some point in a linerly rising part of $S(\theta)$ it will have to obtain the value $0$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: I think, two details could make your answer simpler. 1) $\theta_i$ takes every value in $(-\pi, \pi]$ uniformly during the full rotation, therefore, $\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \theta_i(\theta) d\theta = 0$. 2) $S(\theta)$ attains every value between $\min S(\theta)$ and $\max S(\theta)$.

Comment: @dEmigOd from your formulation of the question, using a "uniform distribution" of the points and using "uniformly" again here, makes me assume that you come from a probability background. My answer to the problem doesn't take any kind of distribution into account, it works for all choices of $\theta_i$. For 2), if you can give a simpler proof of that than I did, I'd like to see it. Because $S(\theta)$ is discontinuous, the statement isn't (AFAIK) some application of a known theorem.

Answer (score 0):

How about using $\theta=\frac{-(\theta_1+\theta_2+\cdots+\theta_n)}{n}$?

Then 
$$\begin{array}{rcl} \theta_1(\theta)+\cdots+\theta_n(\theta)&=&(\theta_1+\theta)+\cdots+(\theta_n+\theta)\\  &=&(\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_n)+(n\theta) \\
&=& (\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_n)+n \left(-\frac{\theta_1+\cdots \theta_n }{n} \right)\\
&=&0
\end{array} $$

Comment: How does this account for the possibility that one of the angles changes by $2\pi$?

Comment: If it changes by $2\pi$, isn't the angle still in the direction of $0$?  (I.e., equivalent to $0 \pmod{2\pi}$?)

Comment: If we take for example triplet $(\pi, \pi, -\pi+\varepsilon)$, then the average is roughly $\dfrac{1}{3}\pi$. Subtracting $\dfrac{1}{3}\pi$ from all angles creates a triplet $(\dfrac{2}{3}\pi, \dfrac{2}{3}\pi, \dfrac{2}{3}\pi - \varepsilon)$ with a sum of $2\pi$.

Comment: I thought you were adjusting by $2\pi$ when outside the range $(-\pi,\pi]$, so the result would be equivalent to $0$.

Comment: The individual angles are adjusted, but not the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sum of the shifted angles differs from the sum of the original angles by $n\theta$ plus some multiple of $2\pi$,  the problem can only be solved by taking  $\theta=\theta(k)=-\frac{\theta_1+\cdots +\theta_n}n+\frac{2k\pi}n$ for suitable $k\in\Bbb Z$. This also means that we may assume wlog. that the angles are "normalized" to begin with, i.e., $$\tag1\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_n\in2\pi\Bbb Z$$
and
$$\tag2\theta_1\le\theta_2\le\ldots\le \theta_n. $$
If for each interval $(\frac {2j-n}n\pi,\frac{2(j+1)-n}n\pi]$, $0\le j<n$, we know the number $N_j$ of angles $\theta_i$ are in that interval, then this already determines $\sum\theta_i$ up to an interval $(\alpha,\alpha+2\pi]$, and so by $(1)$ determines it completely.
Hence for any $n$-tuple $\mathbf N=(N_0, \ldots, N_{n-1})$ of non-negative integers $N_j$ with $\sum N_j=n$, we can let 
$$ F(\mathbf N)=\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i$$
where $\sum\theta_i$ is a multiple of $2\pi$ and exactly $N_j$ of the $\theta_i$ are in $(\frac {2j-n}n\pi,\frac{2(j+1)-1}n\pi]$; by the remark above, this is well-defined.
If we define the rotation of such a tuple, $$\operatorname{rot}(N_0,\ldots, N_{n-1}):=(N_1,\ldots, N_{n-1},N_0),$$ then our goal is to 
 find, for each valid $\mathbf N$, some $k\in\Bbb Z$ with $F(\operatorname{rot}^k\mathbf N)=0$.

Note that by the condition on the $\theta_i$, 
$$ \tag3\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(\tfrac jn-\tfrac12)N_j<F(\mathbf N)\le 1+ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(\tfrac jn-\tfrac12)N_j$$
so that 
$$ F(\mathbf N)=\left\lfloor1+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(\tfrac jn-\tfrac12)N_j\right\rfloor.$$
It follows that
$$\tag4 F(\operatorname{rot}\mathbf N)=F(\mathbf N)-1+N_0\ge F(\mathbf N)-1.$$

If we sum over all  rotations of a period, i.e., 
with $$G(\mathbf N):=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}F(\operatorname{rot}^k\mathbf N),$$we find from $(3)$ that
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(\tfrac jn-\tfrac12)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}N_k<G(\mathbf N)\le n+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(\tfrac jn-\tfrac12)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}N_k,$$
i.e., 
$$ -\frac n2<G(\mathbf N)\le \frac n2.$$
Therefore it is neither possible that all $F(\operatorname{rot}^k\mathbf N)$ of a period are positive nor that all are negative. As Hence there must exist some $k\in\Bbb N$ with $F(\operatorname{rot}^k\mathbf N)\ge 0$ and $F(\operatorname{rot}^{k+1}\mathbf N)\le 0$. Using $(4)$, we conclude that one of $F(\operatorname{rot}^k\mathbf N)$, $F(\operatorname{rot}^{k+1}\mathbf N)$ must be $=0$. $\square$